# Are antiparticles just antivibrations in their counter particle's quantum fields?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter

like particles are vibrations in their quantum fields
are their corresponding anti particle a anti vibration of some sort?
and if so does this diagram accurately represent it?

(If I'm wrong please explain with diagrams and in layman's terms)

[image]

Comment: Repost of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/560485/ with new mention of “antivibration”.